# Using an ID and username for slugs (route model binding)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

So by default I do not require a user to create a username on registration. So their username won't be set, and instead their UID will be their id rather than a username like so:

```php
/**
 * Get the Username
 */
public function getUsernameAttribute()
{
    if($this->attributes['username']){
        return $this->attributes['username'];
    }

    return $this->id;
}
```

So whenever they visit a URL that is has route model binding, it will get their information (the ID)

But now let's say I want to use a username for the route model biding as well in case they **have** updated and set a username I can do that like so:

```php
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Which works for usernames. Now my problem is, it no longer works for those without usernames (ids) and instead is looking for usernames:

```php
where username = ?
```

Due to the way route model binding works, and the load order, I can not do an if statement to check if their username exists, because, well, how would laravel know to get either an ID or username.

Is there a way around this without creating a pull-request? Have any of you experienced something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you scroll past the `getRouteKeyName` section in the docs, you'll find a section on customising the resolution logic.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#explicit-binding

This allows you to specify the query that is run to find a model. E.g.

```php
// RouteServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
        return User::where(function ($query) use ($value) {
                return $query->where('id', $value)->orWhere('username', $value);
            })
            ->firstOrFail();
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, excatly what I was looking for, thanks. (will accept in 4 mins)

Comment: quite easier than i imagined when i started to search.